# How can I implement checkboxes that will input into a column of my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, checkbox

My form currently contains a text input box for the condition section, and whatever is input there goes under the item's condition column. How can I turn this into checkboxes, so that any/all boxes that are checked (ex: New, Slightly Used, Moderately used, Heavily Used) input the value/s of those boxes into the items respective condition section? My current form code is below:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Keyword %>
    <%= f.text_area :keyword, placeholder: "'Ex: iPhone 5 16gb'" %>
  </div>


<br><br>


  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Price_Range %>
  <%= f.text_area :min, placeholder: "'Ex: 300'" %>
  </div>
  -
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.text_area :max, placeholder: "'Ex: 500'" %>
  </div>


<br><br>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Condition %>
    <%= f.text_area :condition, placeholder: "'Ex: Used'" %>
  </div>


   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a radio button for this. You don't want to be able to check "New" and "Heavily Used" at the same time, right?

Comment: See the Docs for the `radio_button` method for `form_for` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button

Comment: Actually I do want that. For example, a user could mark New and Slightly Used, meaning the item could be in either condition.

Comment: So if a user clicks "New" and "Heavily Used" wouldn't that be kind of confusing to users? I would recommend a radio button group of conditions, that would go into the :condition column. What you are looking to do would end up with a column in the database that is storing a group of words based on condition. i.e. one might be "New", and another might be "New Slightly Used" or even "New Heavily Used" (though that sound contradictory). You could do this with checkboxes that get concatenated into one string then stored in the DB.

Comment: BUT, later on you will have problems actually doing anything useful with that data. If they check one or two boxes, you now how 10 possible results. It may seem pointless now, but good design should allow you to easily manipulate that data later. A radio button restricts your possible answers to 4. Maybe a set of radio buttons for "New", "Used", etc. and then another row of buttons for cosmetic condition "Scratches", Wear Marks", ect.

Comment: You might check out how somewhere like Amazon.com uses definitions: http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=1161242 I'm sure eBay has some guides too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I highly discourage this approach, but here's an answer:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :c1 %>
    <%= f.label :c1, "New", :class => "checkbox inline" %>

    <%= f.check_box :c2 %>
    <%= f.label :c2, "Slightly Used", :class => "checkbox inline" %>

    <%= f.check_box :c3 %>
    <%= f.label :c3, "Moderately Used", :class => "checkbox inline" %>

    <%= f.check_box :c4 %>
    <%= f.label :c4, "Heavily Used", :class => "checkbox inline" %>
</div>
```

You will have to whitelist c1..c4 in your params hash if you are using Rails 4

```
params.require......permit(:c1, :c2, :c3, c4..........
```

I don't know the exact structure in your params.permit so I've just put in the dots.

You would then have to concatenate the the strings with whatever separator you want, a space, a slash, a comma. One problem you will run into is any checkbox that is not checked is NOT forwarded by the browser, so if only "New" is checked you will have c2..c4 being `nil`. That is not a huge problem but you will have to be careful how you join them. If they are in an array you can just use `array.join(' ')` but if they are just variables of strings you can't do `c1 + c2 +c3` as you will get an error. Once you have them as a string, you can then save it to that column in the DB.

I would at LEAST **consider having 4 columns in the DB, one for each condition,** that is a type of boolean. That way you can just have each instance variable for the column represented in the params by it's name in the column.